# Overloading [] operator and copy constructor doesn't work

Tags: c++, overloading, destructor

I have a huge problem with overloading `[]` i used it exactly as shown in examples and it doesn't work it is not even seen by compiler.

I get the error:

> no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << * moj

The second problem is that even if I use copy construct if I delete original object the copied one dissapears. But now when i added destructor program just crashes.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Duke\Moje dokumenty\MaciekK\String\main.cpp|90|error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << * moj'|
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class String{
public:
 char* napis;
 int dlugosc;

    char & operator[](int el) {return napis[el];}
    const char & operator[](int el) const {return napis[el];}
    String(char* napis){
    this->napis = napis;
    this->dlugosc = this->length();
 }

String(const String& obiekt){

    int wrt = obiekt.dlugosc*sizeof(char);
    //cout<<"before memcpy"<<endl;
    memcpy(this->napis,obiekt.napis,wrt);

    //cout<<"after memcpy"<<endl;
    this->dlugosc = wrt/sizeof(char);
}

~String(){
    delete[] this->napis;
}

int length(){
    int i = 0;
    while(napis[i] != '\0'){
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}


void show(){
    cout<<napis<<" dlugosc = "<<dlugosc<<endl;
}



 };




int main()
{

String* moj = new String("Ala ma kota");
 //  cout<< moj[0] <<endl;  // I GETT ERROR NO MATH FOR OPERATO<< IN STD:: COUTN<< * MOJ
String* moj2  = new String(*moj);

moj->show();
delete moj;
moj2->show();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the **exact** error message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `moj` is a `String *`, not a `String`.  So `moj[0]` does not invoke your `operator <<`, it just dereferences the pointer.

Comment: cout<<&moj[0] <<endl;
This will print an adress
How should I correct overloading?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that:

Calling deallocation functions on any address not returned by memory allocation functions is an **Undefined Behavior**.
You have an Undefined Behavior in your code, because You never allocate memory using `new []` but you call `delete []` in destructor(`delete[] this->napis;`).

You are not implementing the constructor & the copy constructor correctly.
You need to allocate dynamic memory in constructor and also in the copy constructor. Currently you do not allocate memory in the constructor and in copy constructor you perform a **shallow copy** instead of an deep copy.

You should have:

```
String(char* napis)
{
    //I put 20 as size just for demonstration, You should use appropriate size here.
    this->napis = new char[20];   <-------------- This is Important!
    memcpy(this->napis,napis,12);
    this->dlugosc = this->length();
}

String(const String& obiekt)
{

    int wrt = obiekt.dlugosc*sizeof(char);
    this->napis = new char[wrt];  <-------------- This is Important!
    memcpy(this->napis,obiekt.napis,wrt);
    this->dlugosc = wrt/sizeof(char);
}
```

Also, You need to call `delete` on `moj2` to avoid a memory leak at the end of program.

```
delete moj2;
```

**[Here](http://ideone.com/LkyOn)** is the online version of your program with above said modifications and it works just fine.

Comment: AWESOME! I forgot totally forgot that I need to do it!
But what about that overloaded operator. If I uncommment line 63 as here http://wklej.org/id/760541/ 
I get this:
63|error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << *(moj2 + 16u)'|

but i'd like to get a third letter of the napis.